# AngularJS: Remember credentials for login form

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to allow the user to remember their credentials in my application, here is the code for my form:

```
<form id="loginForm" ng-model="errLoginMsg" ng-submit="login()" >
    <div class="row">
        <p class="validation-error">{{errLoginMsg}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" tabindex="1" id="username" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" class="form-control" ng-model="credentials.Username" placeholder="User Name" />
        <a href="#/forgot/username" class="pull-right small-link">Forgot username?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" tabindex="2" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="credentials.Password" placeholder="Password" />
        <a href="#/forgot/password" class="pull-right small-link">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In Android 4.2 browser (not chrome), it is asking the user if they wish to store their credentials, but then it doesn't work next time the user arrives at the site. On iPhone, it doesn't work at all.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll want to look at the $cookies service.
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookies :)

Comment: or ngStorage: [http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage).

Comment: In my experience, ngStorage is the best way to save items for later.